# Best way to implement models with many overlapping fields in Django?

Tags: django

I need to implement the following logic: there is a big model `Base` with many fields and several smaller models sharing some field subsets with it and with each other. For example, let's say that `Base` has fields `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`; model `A` has fields `a`, `b`, `g`; model `B` has fields `b`, `c`, `d`, `g`; model `C` has fields `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`.

Trying to do proper inheritance from abstract models will very quickly lead to a mess, but making manual copies of fields also seems suboptimal, since every field from the main model is present in the smaller ones and so will have to be listed twice. What's a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit from `Base` and make it to be [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) .
And then override fields that you don't need with `None`.

Django documentation mentions [this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) .
`Fields inherited from abstract base classes can be overridden with another field or value, or be removed with None.`